# How to queue a task after a task group in celery?

Tags: celery, django-celery

How can I ensure that a task runs automatically after a group (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups) has completed its execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a 'Chord':

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords

The first argument is a list of subtasks (the group) and the second argument is the subtask to call when all the subtasks in the first argument are done processing.